# Property or indexer 'Settings.golds' cannot be assigned to -- it is read only

Tags: c#

```
int playerhealth = 15;
int playerstrength = 25;
int playerluck = 2;

public int enemyhealth;
public int enemystrength;
public int enemyluck;

public int gainedgold;
public int gold;

public int desire = 100;
public int desiretaken;

int level;
  ................


Properties.Settings.Default.golds = gold;     //here's the error
```

Please can anyone help me with this error?

> Property or indexer 'Settings.golds' cannot be assigned to -- it is read only

Comment: It's scope is `Application`, change it to `User` and you can change it programmatically

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are trying to set an **Application** scoped setting at run time which is *not* allowed. It is allowed *only* if the setting being updated is a **User** scoped setting.

Here is how you achieve it for a **User** scoped setting:

- Go to project properties (Press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> when project file has the focus in solution explorer)
- Then, go to **Settings** tab (Refer screenshot)
- Now set the **Scope** attribute of **golds** setting to **User** (Refer screenshot)
- Now press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> to save the new changes.

Thus, the compilation error you are facing shall go away.

[image]